# Change data source encoding of GetFeatureInfo response for a WMS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, getfeatureinfo, encoding

How do I change the data source encoding of the *GetFeatureInfo* Request of a WMS-Layer in QGIS 2.18.x/3.x? I can't find any setting to handle the encoding. I need UTF-8 encoding for special characters like 'ä;ö;ü;ß' of a german WMS-Service.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the "Identify Results" shows a wrong charset.

[image: Screenshot WMS identify result]

Comment: is this for the name of the layer? or something else?

Comment: WMS has no attributes, what do you want to change the encode for?

Comment: WMS contain images, therefore you don't need to fiddle with any encoding.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto what do you mean "WMS as no attributes"? Assuming you mean "WMS *has* no attributes", then that is incorrect, the WMS `GetFeatureInfo`  request returns layer attributes.

Comment: @MAP, can you try this [ISO 8859-1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1)? It always adjusts my [Umlaute](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut) and [Eszett](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F).

Comment: I added a screenshot. I'm not serving the WMS. The identify results are not interpreted in the correct charset like UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1.

Comment: In your example you've requested text/plain which [defaults to us-ascii](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_1_Text.html), so that might be your issue. What if you call text/html or application/vnd.ogc.gml

Answer (score 1):

> I added a screenshot. I'm not serving the WMS. The identify results are not interpreted in the correct charset like UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1.

The results are returned in text/plain which defaults to [us-ascii](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_1_Text.html) so I'm not sure it's correct to say the results are not interpreted in the correct charset.

Rather than use text/plain you can retrieve using using text/html and application/vnd.ogc.gml which are likely to have other encodings.

There is no way as far as I know to request a different encoding through a GetFeatureInfo request, so your options are limited.